# Select dynamically created elements which have the same class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have **multiple divs(containing input fiels with some unique id in each)** which were created **dynamically** by ejs so they all contain **same class name**.

I want to make **ajax call** from **only that one div's form(matching the unique id)** using jquery. How can i do that?

I found lots of similar questions on google but not what i am looking for.
Also before you mark this for duplicate, atleast **help** me with this.

This is my code:

In ejs:

```
<% elements.forEach(e => { %>
  <input class="uniqId" value="<%=e.id%>">
  <button type="button" class="btn">
<% }) %> //looping through all the data i have and storing unique value in input field
```

In the javascript/jquery part:

```
$('.btn').on('click', () => {
    $('input.uniqId').val();

    //and then i want to perform ajax call from that specific input field data(the one whose button i clicked)
});
```

Comment: `$(document).on('click', '.btn', function() { var val = $(this).prev('input').val(); });`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan wow that works! sorry if its already asked, i am new to programming. can you provide some links/documentations to know about how siblings and parents work in jquery and javascript? Thanks again.

Comment: I'd suggest Googling for what you asked - this is the first hit which seems to be a good guide: https://medium.com/@timothyrobards/javascript-fundamentals-master-the-dom-part-2-bef36405598e

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks i'll definitely look into it. But i have a doubt about how does this work. Shouldn't it get values from all the previous dom elements of ".btn" class(all input fields) elements since there are more than one of them in the document actually?

Comment: No, as it uses `prev()` to only get the previous sibling `input` of the `button` which was clicked

Comment: No i mean there are multiple buttons with the class:btn and hence multiple input field before each prev class button, within the whole document right? so does it mean the on() event-binder selects the dom differently than normal selectors?

Comment: Ah. Yes it does. Instead of attaching an event handler to every `.btn` element it add a single event handler to a parent element (the document in my example above) and listens for all events bubbling up through the DOM to see if they were `.btn` elements and then run the handler logic.

Comment: ok so now it makes sense. Thanks so much for clarity.